# My JSON is parsing incorrectly. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I am trying to run a small script just to read a two column CSV, convert to JSON, and send to a service. The code should be fairly straight-forward I think :

```
#read excel
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\CSV_1.csv')

# Randomly sample 3% of your dataframe
df_10 = df.sample(frac=0.03)

#convert excel to json for testing
json_file=df_10.to_json()

source = json.loads(json_file)

for row in source:
    player = row[0]
    team = row[1]
```

The issue is that row[0] and row[1] seem to be the first character in each column of my CSV....not the full row. My CSV was originally of the format

```
Player, Team
```

Am I parsing my JSON incorrectly or how can I read the correct data here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`source` is a dictionary, so you're iterating over keys in a dictionary, not rows in a csv.

Without seeing the json itself, it's hard to know exactly what you are going for. But when you do `row[0]` your taking a slice of a string (luckily json requires the key portion to be a string, so you won't get hit with type errors), which explains why you are seeing the first letter of that column (and `team` should likewise be the second letter of that same column)

You probably want to iterate over the .items() of the dictionary, would be my guess.

`for k, v in source.items():`

and then you would do stuff with `k` and `v`, the key and value portions of the dictionary items respectively.